# scala: how to avoid mutables inside try catch blocks

Tags: scala, exception, immutability

I'm trying to avoid mutables variables, but the problem is that I have to access a val that I need to initialize inside the try (it's a db operation that migth fail) and I need that var in the finally block

I tried with several alternatives:

declaring the val inside the try block

```
try {
  val resultSet = SQL(sql).resultSet
  return ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData)
} catch {
  case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error getting metadata")
} finally {
  resultSet.close
}

error: not found: value resultSet
```

declaring the val outside the try block without initializing it

```
val resultSet: java.sql.ResultSet
try {
  resultSet = SQL(sql).resultSet
  return ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData)
} catch {
  case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error getting metadata")
} finally {
  resultSet.close
}

error: only classes can have declared but undefined members
```

using a var, which seems to work

```
var resultSet: java.sql.ResultSet = null
try {
  resultSet = SQL(sql).resultSet
  return ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData)
} catch {
  case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error getting metadata")
} finally {
  resultSet.close
}
```

and finally nesting try-catch block, which seems rather dirty

```
try {
  val resultSet = SQL(sql).resultSet
  try {
    return ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData)
  } catch {
    case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error getting metadata")
  } finally {
    resultSet.close
  }
} catch {
  case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error opening resultSet")
}
```

Is there some better approach I can take to avoid using vars and nesting try-catch blocks?

Answer (score 3):

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

allCatch.either(SQL(sql).resultSet).right.flatMap{ resultSet =>
  val ans = allCatch.either(ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData))
  resultSet.close
  ans
}.fold(e => throw e, identity)
```

or you can skip the `fold` and keep the exception(s) packaged in `Left`.

Answer (score 2):

from this question [functional try & catch w/ Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149009/functional-try-catch-w-scala)

I learned about the loan pattern: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan

Play framework itself seems to use it with the DB.withConnection method

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, `try` block is [an expression](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#try-expressions). In your case it can evaluate to a tuple containing both `val`s:

```
val res: (java.sql.ResultSet, ColumnInfo) = try {
  val rs = SQL(sql).resultSet
  (rs, ColumnInfo(rs.getMetaData))
} catch {
  case _: Throwable => throw new Exception("Error getting metadata")
} finally {
  res._1.close
}
val columnInfo = res._2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the first catch block:

```
try {
  val resultSet = SQL(sql).resultSet
  try {
    ColumnInfo(resultSet.getMetaData)
  } finally {
    resultSet.close
  }
} catch {
  case e => throw new ColumnInfoException("Error opening resultSet")
}
```

Comment: the second catch would also catch any exception from the first try, right? (upvoted, cause it improves my own version...)

Comment: Yes, it will close the result set, but leave the catching to the outer try block.