# Disposable Resource Pattern

Tags: scala, resource-cleanup, disposable

Is there anything standardized within the Scala library to support the ***disposable resource pattern***?

I mean something similar to that supported by C# and .NET just to mention one.

For example does official Scala library provide something like this:

```
trait Disposable { def dispose() }

class Resource extends Disposable

using (new Resource) { r =>

}
```

Note: I'm aware of this article «[Scala finally block closing/flushing resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865754/scala-finally-block-closing-flushing-resource/8865960#8865960)» but it seems not integrated within the standard lib

Answer (score 7):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides a dedicated resource management utility: [`Using`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html).

You will just have to provide an implicit definition of how to release the resource, using the [`Releasable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$$Releasable$.html) trait:

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.util.Using.Releasable

case class Resource(field: String)

implicit val releasable: Releasable[Resource] = resource => println(s"closing $resource")

Using(Resource("hello world")) { resource => resource.field.toInt }
// closing Resource(hello world)
// res0: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hello world")
```

Note that you can place the implicit releasable in the companion object of `Resource` for clarity.

---

Note that you can also use Java's [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) instead of `Using.Releasable` and thus any Java or Scala object implementing `AutoCloseable` (such as `scala.io.Source` or `java.io.PrintWriter`) can directly be used with `Using`:

```
import scala.util.Using

case class Resource(field: String) extends AutoCloseable {
  def close(): Unit = println(s"closing $this")
}

Using(Resource("hello world")) { resource => resource.field.toInt }
// closing Resource(hello world)
// res0: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hello world")
```

Answer (score 2):

At this time you will need to look to the [Scala ARM](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) for a common implementation. Though, as you mentioned, it is a separate library.

For more information:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149144/1072626) at [functional try & catch w/ Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5149009/1072626) links to the Loan Pattern on the scala wiki which has code samples. (I am not re-posting the link because link is subject to change)

[Using a variable in finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627599/using-a-variable-in-finally-block) has a few answers showing ways you could write your own.