# How to ensure a resource is closed in a for-comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala

How is functions with side-effects best handled in for-comprehensions in Scala?

I have a for comprehension that starts by creating a kind of resource (**x**) by calling a function **f1**. This resource has a **close**-method that needs to be called at the end but also if the for-comprehension fails somehow (unless.

So we have something like:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

trait Resource {
  def close() : Unit
}

// Opens some resource and returns it as Success or returns Failure
def f1 : Try[Resource] = ...
def f2 : Try[Resource] = ...

val res = for {
  x <- f1
  y <- f2
} yield {
  (x,y)
}
```

Where should I call the close method? I can call it at the end of the for-comprehension as the last statement (z <- x.close), in the yield-part, or after the for-comprehension (res._1.close). None of them ensures that **close** is called if an error occurs (e.g. if **f2** fails).
Alternatively, I could separate

```
x <- f1
```

out of the for-comprehension like this:

```
val res = f1
res match {
  case Success(x) => {
    for {
      y <- f2
    }
    x.close
  }

  case Failure(e) => ...       
:
```

That would ensure the call of close but is not very nice code.
Is there not a smarter and more clean way to achieve the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Automatic Resource Management alternatives exists for Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207425/what-automatic-resource-management-alternatives-exists-for-scala)

Answer (score 8):

When I have such problem I decide between 2 possibilities:

1. Use [Scala ARM](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm)
2. Implement [Loan Pattern](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan) on my own (link is volatile and could die)

In most cases I prefer own implementation to avoid additional dependency.
Here is the code of Loan Pattern:

```
def using[A](r : Resource)(f : Resource => A) : A =
    try {
        f(r)
    } finally {
        r.close()
    }
```

Usage:

```
using(getResource())(r =>
    useResource(r)
)
```

Since you need 2 resources you will need to use this pattern twice:

```
using(getResource1())(r1 =>
    using(getResource2())(r2 =>
        doYourWork(r1, r2)))
```

You can also look on following answers:

- [Scala: Disposable Resource Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523192/scala-disposable-resource-pattern)
- [functional try & catch w/ Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149009/functional-try-catch-w-scala)
- [Using a variable in finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627599/using-a-variable-in-finally-block)

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern for closing resources is the loan pattern:

```
type Closable = { def close(): Unit }

def withClosable[B](closable: Closable)(op: Closable => B): B = {
  try {
    op(closable)
  } finally {
    closable.close()
  }
}
```

With a little refactoring you can use this pattern:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

trait Resource {
  def close() : Unit
}

// Opens some resource and returns it as Success or returns Failure
def f1(res: Resource) : Try[Resource] = ???
def f2(res: Resource) : Try[Resource] = ???

val f1Resource: Resource = ???
val f2Resource: Resource = ???

val res = for {
  x <- withClosable(f1Resource)(f1)
  y <- withClosable(f2Resource)(f2)
} yield {
  (x,y)
}
```

or

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

trait Resource {
  def close() : Unit
}

// Opens some resource and returns it as Success or returns Failure
def f1: Try[Resource] = { 
  val res: Resource = ???
  withClosable(res){ ... }
}
def f2: Try[Resource] = { 
  val res: Resource = ???
  withClosable(res){ ... }
}

val res = for {
  x <- f1
  y <- f2
} yield {
  (x,y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm

If your "resource" does not implement java.io.Closeable (or some other closable interface, supported by than library) you just need to write an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def yourEnititySupport[A <: your.closable.Enitity]: Resource[A] = 
  new Resource[A] {
    override def close(r: A) = r.commit()
    // if you need custom behavior here
    override def closeAfterException(r: A, t: Throwable) = r.rollback()
  }
```

And use it like this:

```
import resource._

for {
  a <- managed(your.closable.Enitity())
  b <- managed(your.closable.Enitity())
} { doSomething(a, b) }
```

Comment: In my case, it is important that the resource is kept open while all steps in the for-comprehension are executed and not closed until the last one succeeded - or one steps failed.
To me it looks like the suggestions above close the resource after each step. 

It should be similar to:

* open resource
* if succeeding, execute for-comprehension where the resource is used.
* if opening the resource failed do nothing.
* after for-comprehension: close the resource. In case the for-comprehension fails, close as well.

I hope this explains it.

Comment: What do you mean by "each step"? Suggested code closes managed resources after whole block { doSomething(a, b) } is executed.